# Show/hide progress bar hosted in another component

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-components

I'm a rookie to Angular. I want to show/hide a `mat-progress-bar` that is on `ToolbarComponent` from any other component.

I already searched about parent/child relationship between components, but this is not the case here (at least is what I think).

This is my project structure:

- src

  - app
  - components

    - company

      - company.component.ts
  - shared

    - components

      - toolbar

        - toolbar.component.ts

How can I access the `mat-progress-bar` that is on `ToolbarComponent` from the `CompanyComponent`, for example? Or there's a better way to do what I want?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hide the toolbar on some screens for example on login screen the best way to do it with your structure is to use Observable and Subscribe to it globally to change anything anywhere across your components. To do this define a store as follow:--

```
//Store.js
import {Observable, BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs';

export class Store<T> {
    state$: Observable<T>;
    private _state$: BehaviorSubject<T>;

    protected constructor (initialState: T) {
        this._state$ = new BehaviorSubject(initialState);
        this.state$ = this._state$.asObservable();
    }

    get state (): T {
        return this._state$.getValue();
    }

    setState (nextState: T): void {
        this._state$.next(nextState);
    }
}
```

Then define a file say

```
//ToolbarState.ts
const state = {
  show: false
}
export class ToolbarState {
  state: {show: boolean} = state;
}
```

Then a store file to communicate with this state lets say:-

```
//ToolbarStore.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Store } from '../store';
import { ToolbarState } from './ToolbarState';

@Injectable()
export class ToolbarStore extends Store<ToolbarState> {
  constructor () {
    super(new ToolbarState());
  }

  showToolbar (): void {
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      state: {...this.state.state, show: true}
    });
  }

  hideToolbar (): void {
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      state: {...this.state.state, show: false}
    });
  }
}
```

so in your company component you can do something like below:-

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ToolbarStore } from '../ToolbarStore';

@Component({
  selector: 'company',
  templateUrl: './company.component.html',
  providers: [ToolbarStore]
})
export class CompanyComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public store: ToolbarStore) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.store.showToolbar(); // store function to show toolbar
    });
  }

  hideToolbar(){
    this.store.hideToolbar(); // store function to hide toolbar
  }
}
```

then in your Toolbar.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestory } from '@angular/core';
import { ToolbarStore } from '../ToolbarStore';
import {Subscription} from 'rxjs';

    @Component({
      selector: 'toolbar',
      templateUrl: './toolbar.component.html',
      providers: [ToolbarStore]
    })
    export class ToolbarComponent implements OnInit, OnDestory {


      Subscription: Subscription = new Subscription();
      show: boolean;
      constructor(public store: ToolbarStore) { }

      ngOnInit() {
        this.Subscription.add(
          this.store.state$.subscribe(data => {
            this.show = data.state.show;
          });
        );
      }

      ngOnDestory(){
        this.Subscription.unsubscribe();
      }

    }
```

Your app.module.ts should be like this:-

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HelloComponent } from './hello.component';
import { CompanyComponent } from './company.component';
import { ToolbarComponent } from './toolbar.component';
import { ToolbarStore } from './toolbar-store';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent, CompanyComponent, ToolbarComponent ],
  providers: [ToolbarStore],
  exports: [ToolbarComponent],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

and then finally in your toolbar.component.html file:--

```
<mat-progress-bar *ngIf="show"
          class="example-margin"
          [color]="color"
          [mode]="mode"
          [value]="value"
          [bufferValue]="bufferValue">
      </mat-progress-bar>
```

You can learn more about Behaviour Subject and Observables from the following links:-
https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/subjects/behaviorsubject

Working example of the above code in the stackblitz at following link, here you can control the elements inside toolbar component from company component:-
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-7cmgvm

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think you forgot to add the property 'show' to the ToolbarState class and inside ToolbarComponent, on ngOnInit, I think it's not this.show = data.show.show but this.show = data.state.show. Can you check please? It's not working here as well.

Comment: on ngOninit inside ToolbarComponent, we have added a Subscription to access show value inside ToolbarState which will be accessible as  data.state.show you are right (cheers!!) I have made a little edit in ToolBarStore and ToolbarComponent inside this function showToolbar (): void {
        this.setState({
          ...this.state,
          state: {...this.state.state, show: true}
        });
      }
 please check it should work now.

Comment: Thank you Usman! No errors now, but the mat-progress-bar is not showing up after I call  this.store.showToolbar(); on the company component. Can you check please?

Comment: Get this function out of ngOnInit and call it on click of some button on company component for example:--
<button (click)="showToolbar()">Show Toolbar</button> and in component
showToolbar(){ this.state.showToolbar(); } hope it will help. Thanks!! Or just share your code snippet how you trying to show/hide progress bar in company component. what i posted was a mere example.

Comment: Yes, I know the call function was just an example. I'm not using the timeout function, but I need to call that on ngInit method, just like you did. And it's not working.

Comment: Great! I have made working example for you on Stackblitz kindly check in edit, you must have forgot to mention the ToolbarStore under providers in app.module.ts, that is why its not accessible in any of the component's .ts file check edit in the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Shared Service to manage the "loading status" (like Usman Ali Khan's respnse), but following good practices, it should be in a SharedModule, in order to use it in wherever component.

If you are thinking to use it for HTTP calls, you can use Interceptors.

I have an example using SharedModule + SharedService + Interceptors in my repository: https://github.com/cmandamiento/angular-architecture-base